# How to do this using bash please?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this file,named final.txt, which contains:

```
 Latitude                      36.8962 +-    0.0075 N         0.8348 km
 Latitude                      36.8962 +-    0.0075 N         0.8348 km
 Latitude                      36.8958 +-    0.0075 N         0.8351 km
 Longitude                     15.1930 +-    0.0097 E         0.8624 km
 Longitude                     15.1930 +-    0.0097 E         0.8624 km
 Longitude                     15.1917 +-    0.0097 E         0.8624 km
 Epoch Time             1340759658.852 +-      0.19 sec
 Depth                           10.00 +-      1.57 km
 Depth                           10.00 +-      1.57 km
 Depth                           10.00 +-      1.58 km
 Gap                               248              deg
 Gap                               248              deg
 Gap                               248              deg
```

QUESTION: Given the file named “final.txt” write a script in order to extract the value of latitude, longitude, depth and gap. This information must be stored in a file that it is structured as follows:
Latitude, longitude, depth, gap
(columns separated by commas).

For the extraction part is ok which is:

```
sed -n /Latitude/p final.txt > data.txt
sed -n /Longitude/p final.txt >> data.txt
sed -n /Depth/p final.txt >> data.txt
sed -n /Gap/p final.txt >> data.txt
```

Now the problem is with the structure desired. I want to know how to extract what is written after the word "Latitude" for each of the 3 rows and put them all three of them in one column under each other as shown below.

```
Latitude
 36.8962 +-    0.0075 N         0.8348 km
 36.8962 +-    0.0075 N         0.8348 km
 36.8958 +-    0.0075 N         0.8351 km
```

Any help is appreciated!Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the following output:

```
36.8962 +- 0.0075 N 0.8348 km, 15.1930 +- 0.0097 E 0.8624 km, 10.00 +- 1.57 km, 248 deg
36.8962 +- 0.0075 N 0.8348 km, 15.1930 +- 0.0097 E 0.8624 km, 10.00 +- 1.57 km, 248 deg
36.8958 +- 0.0075 N 0.8351 km, 15.1917 +- 0.0097 E 0.8624 km, 10.00 +- 1.58 km, 248 deg
```

If this is true, I suggest:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

/Latitude/    {$1=""; print > "Lat"}
/Longitude/   {$1=""; print > "Long"}
/Epoch Time/  {                     }
/Depth/       {$1=""; print > "Depth"}
/Gap/         {$1=""; print > "Gap"}


END { system ("paste -d , Lat Long Depth Gap")}
```

Comment: That`s exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The below script will generate output files as `Depth.txt, Epoch.txt, file.txt, Gap.txt, Latitude.txt, Longitude.txt`.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        array[$1][NR]= array[$1][NR] "  "  $i
    }
}

END {
    for (i in array) {
        print(i)  > i".txt"
        for (j in array[i]) {
            print(array[i][j]) > i".txt"
        }
    }
}
```

Execute the program as

```
$ cat file.txt |./process.awk
```

Output:

```
$ cat Latitude.txt 
Latitude
  36.8962  +-  0.0075  N  0.8348  km
  36.8962  +-  0.0075  N  0.8348  km
  36.8958  +-  0.0075  N  0.8351  km

$ cat Longitude.txt 
Longitude
  15.1930  +-  0.0097  E  0.8624  km
  15.1930  +-  0.0097  E  0.8624  km
  15.1917  +-  0.0097  E  0.8624  km
```

Answer (score 0):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), is it what you expect ?

```
$ awk '{item=$1;$1="";arr[item]=arr[item]"\n"$0}END{for (a in arr) {print a, arr[a]}}' file
Depth 
 10.00 +- 1.57 km
 10.00 +- 1.57 km
 10.00 +- 1.58 km
Epoch 
 Time 1340759658.852 +- 0.19 sec
Gap 
 248 deg
 248 deg
 248 deg
Latitude 
 36.8962 +- 0.0075 N 0.8348 km
 36.8962 +- 0.0075 N 0.8348 km
 36.8958 +- 0.0075 N 0.8351 km
Longitude 
 15.1930 +- 0.0097 E 0.8624 km
 15.1930 +- 0.0097 E 0.8624 km
 15.1917 +- 0.0097 E 0.8624 km
```

Comment: but is there a command that picks what is written after each "Latitude" (i.e. 36.8962 +- 0.0075 N 0.8348 km and the other two)and insert it in a column named Latitude? Instead of putting every number manually.

Comment: and the columns should be next to each other rather then under each other.

Comment: I think you have enough to start searching by yourself ?! See `man gawk`

Comment: I look forward to the followup question "How to do this using awk please?" ;-).